# Restore DB from dockerfile

Tags: sql-server, docker

I'm trying create SQL Server container in Docker and restore DB

My Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Password
ENV MSSQL_COLLATION=Lithuanian_CI_AS
ENV MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433

RUN mkdir -p /var/opt/mssql/backup

COPY ./DVS_demo.bak /var/opt/mssql/backup/DVS_demo.bak
COPY ./DVS_Files.bak /var/opt/mssql/backup/DVS_Files.bak

CMD /bin/bash /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -l 50 -U sa -P "Password" -i "RESTORE DATABASE DVS FROM DISK = '/var/opt/mssql/backup/DVS_demo.bak' WITH MOVE 'mvp_Data' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/DVS_programavimui.mdf', MOVE 'mvp_Log' TO '/var/opt/mssql/data/DVS_programavimui.ldf'" & /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

With -l 50 I wait 50 seconds to boot my container and when trying restore DB, but its not working, maybe someone know what I'm doing wrong? I don't have any errors, SQL server starts but without restored DB.

Comment: and the error you get is?

Comment: I don't have error, server starts but without restored DB

Comment: `sqlcmd` will fail to connect immediately because `sqlservr` hasn't had a chance to start up the system databases yet (that often takes tens of seconds) and open a listening socket to accept incoming connections. Have you read the [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) yet? Did you notice the part about using an `entrypoint.sh` and `setup.sql` script to create a database (or, by extension, restore one/many databases)?